# Why does the last element instantiated on a layout group appear as first and wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, scripting, scriptable-object

I am programming a card game in unity and need the cards drawn to be displayed on a UI area bound by a Horizontal Layout Group, the cards are scriptable objects written in advance and displayed when drawn, but for some reason the last card of the deck I create and shuffle is displayed as a random different card, and moved as the first child of the area.

I tried checking the logic of all the functions involved, I found out that removing the shuffling solves the problem, but while debugging the shuffle function I found everything works as intended, so I concluded it must be only a graphical issue. I've also tried adding a Layout Element and Content Size Fitter but it's no use. I'll leave the DrawCards, CreateDeck and Shuffle functions below, for reference.
Update: rewriting the DrawCards function with a static hand and deck doesn't fix it either.

```
   public class DrawCards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerCard;
    public GameObject playerArea;
    public CardDisplay display; 

public List<Card> Draw(List<Card> deck, int num)
{
    List<Card> handTemp = new List<Card>();
    RectTransform root = playerArea.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        GameObject card = Instantiate(playerCard, playerArea.transform);
        Debug.Log("card instatiated");
        LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(root);
        handTemp.Add(deck[0]);
        Debug.Log(deck[0].name);
        display.Set(deck[0]);
        deck.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    return handTemp;
    
  }

}

private List<Card> CreateDeck()
{
    List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        deck.Add(startingCards[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        //Debug.Log(i);
        deck.Add(startingCards[i]);
    }
    //Debug.Log("deck created");
    return deck;
}

public void Shuffle(List<Card> zone)
{
    int count = zone.Count;
    //Debug.Log("count" + count);
    int last = count - 1;
    //Debug.Log("last" + last);
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
    {
        int random = Random.Range(i, count);
        //Debug.Log("random " + random);
        Card tmp = zone[i];
        //Debug.Log("tmp " + tmp.name);
        //Debug.Log("og " + zone[i].name);
        //Debug.Log("random card " + zone[random].name);
        zone[i] = zone[random];
        //Debug.Log("switched card " + zone[i].name);
        zone[random] = tmp;
        //Debug.Log("switched card " + tmp.name);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Horizontal Layout Group?

Comment: yes, to keep the cards in place, why? I can send a screenshot of the inspector if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting just in case anyone has a similar issue: I solved the problem, the issue is on the DrawCards function: since I was calling the Set function on the top card of the deck *after* instantiating it, the first card would always instantiate "unset", i.e. randomly. Moving the Set call before the Instantiate fixes the glitch.